# linux shell script input line

Tags: shell

quick question, how do I write a shell script that prompts users to enter let say 5  lines and it will stores those lines into a .txt file  for example,

```
Today is hot 
Today is code 
Today is chilly
Today is windy
Today is sunny
```

not like

```
Today is hot  Today is code  Today is chilly Today is windy today is sunny
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It depends on the shell.

Comment: You are aware that that's _four_ lines, aren't you, and that 'code' is not a adjective? :-)

Comment: If you're getting everything on one line when you do an `echo` it may be because you're not quoting a variable. Since you don't show any code, it's impossible to say for sure, but that scenario fits the two examples you show in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash you can do:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
  read line
  echo $line >> file.txt
done
```

Comment: Or `... read -r line; echo "$line"; done > file.text` - add `-r` to accept backslashes literally, quote the variable to preserve whitespace and do all your output at once.

Answer (score 0):

Does this count?

```
sed 5q > file.txt
```